# Can analysis of GWAS/WES/WGS be performed with DNA from saliva in combination with DNA from blood?

Tags: statistics, genetics, genome, sequencing, gwas

Can statistical analyses (GWAS/WES/WGS) be performed with DNA from saliva in combination with DNA from blood? Is there a chance of bias? First, I think DNA=DNA, in other words, no matter how the 'DNA code' is collected. But there may be unexpected and unseen problems. Then, I think, a variable 'type-dna' for Saliva/Blood can be added for statistical analyses and checked whether this variable is significant or not.
What is your advice and opinion?

Greetings and thank you in advance,
Roberto